# Agrupar tabelas em uma única

Tags: delphi, postgresql

Estamos atualizando um sistema desenvolvido em Delphi q armazenava os dados em tabelas access para PostgreSQL. Até aí tudo bem, porém, me deparei com a seguinte situação:

No banco antigo tínhamos as seguintes tabelas para armazenar as movimentações:

- notafiscal
- notafiscalitem
- pedido
- pedidoitem
- cupom
- cupomitem
- notasentrada
- notasentradaitem

Para padronizar pensei em agrupar tudo facilitando atualização de campos e agrupar tudo em uma única tabela (sic):

- movimentacao
- movimentacaoitem

Criando um campo que diferenciasse um lançamento do outro.

Isso pode causar lentidão? É uma técnica aceitável? Quais os prós e contras?

Comment: Só para padronizar? Não tem um motivo mais palpável? Eu já usei esse modelo (as tabelas chamavam-se "documento" e "documentoItem") e o problema é a enorme quantidade de campos que elas acabaram atingindo (mais de 500 colunas cada uma). Daí: campos redundantes porque ninguém mais sabia o que se podia reutilizar, mesmo campo para diferentes propósitos, campos nulos porque não faziam sentido para todos os registros, lentidão e impossibilidade de deletar registros dada a quantidade de FK. Mas tudo isso depende de muitos fatores. Por isso pergunto se você tem outros motivos além da "padronização".

Comment: alem da padronizacao, pra mim facilitaria na atualizacao, pois, algumas campos sao adicionados em ambas as tabelas, um exemplo seria nota fiscal e nota fiscal de entrada.... pensando noq falaste realmente vai ser necessario mtas colunas... acredito q alguns documentos seja possivel agrupar, orcamentos, pedidos, condicionais, mas nao todos...

Comment: Algumas vezes o campo tem propósito semelhante e nome idêntico mas não é o mesmo campo pois pertence a entidades distintas. Considere: `NotaFiscal.Número e Série e Ano` e `NotaFiscalEntrada.Número e Série e Ano`. A primeira não pode ser repetida enquanto a segunda tem uma probabilidade de receber dados repetidos. Mesmo que você use uma surrogate key (um campo sequencial e sem significado para o negócio) como PK da sua tabela, o fato é que estes campos pertencem a entidades distintas então podem estar "repetidos" em diferentes tabelas.

Comment: realmente, pensando dessa maneira e para garantir a distincao dos registros, a melhor forma seria uma tabela para cada tipo de documento... o preco da padronizacao  e da facilidade de possiveis atualizacoes é menor doq o do gerenciamento de tabelas gigantes...

Answer (score 1):

A normalização serve para garantir que os dados sejam distintos e que haja uma melhor manutenção dos dados no seu caso, por tanto o banco antigo é normalizado em distinção da "atualização" do banco que está na forma apresentado como uma tabela "faz tudo" que possui muitos dados que não podem ser agrupados ou são "repetidos":
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
[image: Normalização de Dados]

Você pode normalizar seguindo o padrão das 5 Formas Normais(FNs) dado esse exemplo abaixo de uma locadora por ser mais simples e apresentar menos tabelas após ser normatizada:
[image: 1FN]

[image: 2FN]

[image: 3FN]

[image: 4FN]

Comment: Parece que não foi você que fez estes slides. Eles podem ser reproduzidos sem problemas? Você poderia citar a fonte?

Comment: @bigown esses slides são disponibilizados nesse site http://www.softblue.com.br/ curso de sql completo.. tinha um tempo que tinha visto e lembrei que havia um material que podeira usar pra ajudar no seu problema^^